# CakePHP hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) Delete Joining Record

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM relationship between Users and Locations. Both Models have the appropriate `$hasAndBelongsToMany` variable set.

When I managing User Locations, I want to delete the association between the User and Location, but not the Location. Clearly this Location could belong to other users. I would expect the following code to delete just the join table record provided the HABTM associations, but it deleted both records.

```
$this->Weather->deleteAll(array('Weather.id' => $this->data['weather_ids'], false);
```

However, I am new to CakePHP, so I am sure I am missing something. I have tried setting cascade to false and changing the Model order with User, User->Weather, Weather->User. No luck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite sure how `Weather` is related to your models, so I'll just go with the traditional names, `LocationsUser` is the joining table. This should delete all associations between the user with id `$id` and any locations:

```
$this->User->LocationsUser->deleteAll(array('LocationsUser.user_id' => $id), false);
```

Notice also that you're missing a closing bracket in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the model is actually Weather locations and I used them interchangeably. Your code was spot on, I didn't realize I could reference the association Model. Here's what I had for completeness. Works just right!

`$this->User->UsersWeather->deleteAll(array('UsersWeather.weather_id' => $this->data['weather_ids'], 'UsersWeather.user_id' => $this->user['User']['id']))`