# CakePHP HATBM not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm starting a cakephp app, I've never used it in real world so I'm a bit confused how HABTM works, even though I read the documentation I couldn't get even the `$this->User->Subscription` and didn't see any extra object dumped

What I want is to create a HATBM between users and subscriptions

so I created three tables (users,subscriptions,users_subscribers)

Then in my `User.php` model I did this

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany =
    array(
        'Subscription' =>
            array('className'=>'Subscription',
                'joinTable' => 'users_subscribers',
                'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
               'associationForeignKey'  => 'subscription_id',
                'unique' => true,
               )
        );
```

`SUbscription.php`

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User'=>array('className'=>'User',
                    'joinTable' => 'users_subscribers',
        'foreignKey' => 'subscription_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => true));
```

Even with the tags example and following it, I cannot get the relation set, I also added the line `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` to see if its running which it isn't...

Could anyone guide me how exactly you get HATBM to work, what else do I need to verify?

Full code:
pages_controller.php
http://sao.pastebin.com/PWQMhE2z

User model:
http://sao.pastebin.com/PWqwAj1v

Subscription model:
http://sao.pastebin.com/MfVFR4Kw

subscriptions SCHEMA:
http://sao.pastebin.com/mLRcEp1c

User SCHEMA:
http://sao.pastebin.com/UeTRHh3u

users_subscriptions SCHEMA:
http://sao.pastebin.com/4UeSDZte

Comment: Check with http://cakeapp.com, it's easy to learn about HABTM there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and fastest way to get this working is by following CakePHP's rule of configuration over customization.

This means following the CakePHP conventions unless you have a very good reason not to.

I'd strongly recommend starting with a basic setup that you know works, and then modifying that if you need to. Here's a quick and easy way to get up and running.

**The Database Tables**

Start with three database tables: users, subscriptions and subscriptions_users. The schemas you already have are ok, but I'd make a couple modifications to make sure things go smoothly:

1. Add a `name` or `title` column to the `users` table. Either that, or you'll have to add the `$displayField` property to your User model. If you don't do this you'll miss out on some of the "automagic" that CakePHP provides. [More info on $displayField](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1062/displayField)
2. Change the join table's name to `subscriptions_users`. This is the CakePHP convention and there's no reason not to save yourself the time and worry of following it. :-)
3. Use the following schema for the join table:

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE subscriptions_users (
   > subscription_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   > user_id int(11) NOT NULL
   > ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   > ```

Note that there aren't any keys defined. From the CakePHP manual: "To avoid any issues - don't define a combined primary key for these two fields, if your application requires it you can define a unique index."

**The Models**

Try to keep your code clean. There are a lot of sensible defaults implemented in CakePHP and there's no point in defining them when they're already defined.

The following models should work for you:

**user.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Subscription');
}
?>
```

**subscription.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
}
?>
```

Pretty simple. Just be sure your model files are named correctly: user.php and subscription.php, all lowercase.

Also, note that you don't have to set any of the relationship options (`className`, `joinTable`, etc.) unless they need to be something besides the default. Ninety percent of the time the defaults should serve you just fine.

You should be up and running now. You can make sure the model objects are being loaded and are accessible in your controllers like this:

**users_controller.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';

    function index() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        var_dump(is_object($this->User));
        var_dump(is_object($this->User->Subscription));
    }
}
?>
```

**subscriptions_controller.php**

```
<?php
class SubscriptionsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Subscriptions';

    function index() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        var_dump(is_object($this->Subscription));
        var_dump(is_object($this->Subscription->User));
    }
}
?>
```

The output of /users and /subscriptions should both be `bool(true) bool(true)`.

You can see the full models by doing `pr($this->User);`.

**Deleting records**

If you delete a single record using, for example, `$this->User->delete($user_id)`, all the records in the join table with that user ID will automatically be deleted as well.

If you want to delete a single record from a HABTM join table, without deleting the records that it links to, in effect, "unjoining" the two records, you can do it through the SubscriptionsUser model. This is a model that is created on the fly whenever there's a HABTM relationship.

See here for an example: [CakePHP hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) Delete Joining Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838732/cakephp-hasandbelongstomany-habtm-delete-joining-record/2838977#2838977)

Comment: I can't believe it was just to rename the files, so much for sensible conventions, one last question, how do you delete the relation records if I want to delete subscription, etc etc? could you provide some examples on that?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test app with a basic schema and I get all the relations right.  I suspect your woes have to do with the fact that you did `$uses = array('User', 'Subscription');`Why don't you try with `$uses = $uses = array('User');` and then try

```
$this->User->find('all');
$this->User->Subscription->find('all');
```

Comment: Just did that, it didn't work, using the latest version 1.3.7

Comment: Err, my mistake.  It should be User, not Users.  Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define the same HABTM relation in your `Subscription.php` model. If I recall correctly, CakePHP internally fetches some of the required information from the *other* side's HABTM configuration.

Comment: I did set up the relation in the other side, thing is that I'm not even getting an error, it just loads without the relation created, no error/exception is executed so I'm kind of shooting blindly to see if it hits something =/

Comment: @allenskd: Just to check: did you set debug to 2 in your config? Is your recursion level deep enough in your find() call (i.e. recursion >= 1)? Are you using the Containable behaviour? Can you force any other errors to display (e.g. try calling a method on a non-object, do you see an error)?

Comment: I checked my configuration, it's set to "2", recursion level, tried to change it in various models but didn't work, containable behaviour.. not sure how that works yet. Yes I'm getting errors, I edited my post and included full source and schemas, I'm pretty sure it's either something very small or it just plainly doesn't work....

Comment: I must say that your code looks okay. Are you sure there is related data in the database? You're creating new Subscription instances in your PagesController, but you are not linking them to any User.

Comment: I did link the first user with some subscriptions, it didn't work, the instances there was to get familiar with the output so I inserted a few subscriptions and read them, but whenever I call the user record, the subscription array is not attached in the user array :(, sorry for the late reply, it didn't notify me :(

Comment: Please check again that there are existing relations between existing users and existing subscriptions. I see that you have a commented out User->save() in your controller. You have set your HABTM relation to unique, so everytime you save a model with a relation, you need to pass in *all* existing relations as well, or they will get deleted. PS: What version of CakePHP do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I always use two "hasMany" relations and one "belongsTo" relation to get the HABTM effect in CakePHP with more control.

Try this:

User model (user.php)

```
class User extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'User';
  public $actsAs = array('Containable');
  public $hasMany = array('UserSubscription');
}
```

Subscription model (subscription.php)

```
class Subscription extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Subscription';
  public $actsAs = array('Containable');
  public $hasMany = array('UserSubscription');
}
```

UserSubscription model (user_subscription.php)

```
class UserSubscription extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'UserSubscription';
  public $belongsTo = array('User','Subscription');
}
```

pages/home action (pages_controller.php)

```
public function home() {
  $data = array(
    'User' => array(
      'id' => 1, 'user_email' => 'allenskd@gmail.com', 'user_password' => 'fdfdkert', 'user_salt' => 'haha', 'user_displayname' => 'David'
    ),
    'UserSubscription' => array(
            'user_id' => '1', 'subscription_id' => '1'
    ),
    'Subscription' => array(
      'id' => 1, 'title' => 'My first plan', 'price' => '30.00', 'subscriber_count' => '1'
    ),
  );
  $this->Subscription->save($data);
  $this->User->saveAll($data);
  $test = $this->User->find('all', array('contain' => array('UserSubscription' => array('Subscription'))));
  pr($test);
}
```