# Delete a record in a Join Table of a HABTM Relationship

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

The relationship looks like this:

```
Podcasts <-HABTM-> Users
```

How do I delete the association between them (Inserting works fine)? I searched many threads but I couldn't find a working answer for me. This is what I already have:

**Model/PodcastsUser.php**

```
public function removePodcast($podcastId, $userId){
    if(empty($podcastId) || empty($userId)) return false;

    $this->User->PodcastsUser->deleteAll(array(
        'PodcastsUser.podcast_id' => $this->data['Podcast'][$podcastId], 
        'PodcastsUser.user_id' => $this->data['Podcast'][$userId]
    ));
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function removepodcast($podcastId, $userId){
    //$this->loadModel('PodcastsUser');
    $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('PodcastsUser');

    if ($this->User->removePodcast($podcastId, $userId)){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The podcast has been removed'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
    }else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The podcast could not be removed. Please, try again.'));
        }
}
```

**View/Users/**

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Remove'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'removepodcast', $mypodcast['Podcast']['id'], $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
```

I looked at this [description here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838732/cakephp-hasandbelongstomany-habtm-delete-joining-record/2838977#2838977) but it isn't clearer to me.
Please help me with an example or correction, would be so appreciated!

Comment: You just need to call this function on UserController. $this->User->removePodcast();

Comment: I added more code now

Comment: thanks , what is the issue now ? any error ?

Comment: yes: `Undefined index: Podcast [APP/Model/PodcastsUser.php` and `The podcast has been removed` as flash message. Thank you for your help

Comment: replace $this->data['Podcast'][$podcastId] with podcastId and $this->data['Podcast'][$userId] with $userId in model function

Comment: It works in a strange way: the DB looks right, but `The podcast could not be removed. Please, try again.` appears. This makes no sense to me?

Comment: return true after removePodcast function.